# SwiftUI Chart: how can I overlay multiple graph datas?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, charts, swiftui-charts

here are two charts.
and I would like to show the data of `object` and `object2` together in one chart.

Would it be possible?

```
Chart(db.objects, id: \.self) { object in
    LineMark(
        x: .value("name", object.name),
        y: .value("value", Int(object.value) ?? 0)
    )
}

Chart(db.objects2, id: \.self) { object2 in
    LineMark(
        x: .value("name", object2.name),
        y: .value("value", Int(object2.value) ?? 0)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I just found the way from apple developer website

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chart/

```
struct ProfitOverTime {
    var date: Date
    var profit: Double
}

let departmentAProfit: [ProfitOverTime] = [] // ...
let departmentBProfit: [ProfitOverTime] = [] // ...

var body: some View {
    Chart {
        ForEach(departmentAProfit) {
            LineMark(
                x: .value("Date", $0.date),
                y: .value("Profit A", $0.profit)
            )
            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
        }
        ForEach(departmentBProfit) {
            LineMark(
                x: .value("Date", $0.date),
                y: .value("Profit B", $0.profit)
            )
            .foregroundStyle(.green)
        }
        RuleMark(
            y: .value("Threshold", 500.0)
        )
        .foregroundStyle(.red)
    }
}
```

[image: chart showing overlaid data]

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution. Since the data structure is the same, the data could be one source and displayed using one LineMark.

As an example, dept was added to the model to identify each group of data that represents a single line in the chart:

```
    struct ProfitOverTime {
        var dept: String
        var date: Date
        var profit: Double
    }
```

The data combined into one array:

```
    let data: [ProfitOverTime] = [] // ...
```

The foreground style is based on the department, that is, each line in the chart.

```
struct DepartmentChart: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart(data) {
            LineMark(
                x: .value("Date", $0.date),
                y: .value("Profit", $0.profit)
                series: .value("Department", $0.dept)
            )
            .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Department", $0.dept))
    
            RuleMark(
                y: .value("Threshold", 500.0)
            )
            .foregroundStyle(.red)
        }
        .chartForegroundStyleScale(["Profit A": .green, "Profit B": .blue])
    }
}
```

Series was added to identify each line by its color:

[image]

The chartForegroundStyleScale is optional since each line will automatically be colored differently. But chartForegroundStyleScale can be used to customize the line colors.